# php mysql not selecting a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am a bit confused I have a table called attempts that checks users failed login attempts but it doesn't select that table but if I select another table it works

This doesn't work:

```
$test_q = $config->query("SELECT * FROM attempts");
print_r($test_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

This works:

```
$test_q = $config->query("SELECT * FROM another_table");
print_r($test_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Why is that so?

Comment: error message? error reporting turned on? display errors on?

Comment: Does the table `attempts` have anything in it? Try encapsulating it with ticks like `\`attempts\``

Comment: Did you try executing that query on your MySQL engine, for example using PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Hajo - Yes error reporting is turned on
@Blake - yes there are three rows inserted in it and already tried the encapsulation trick

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Sorry for the late comment yes i tried doing that and it fetched the correct result

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What is it outputting?

Comment: @liquorvicar - I mean it doesn't work no error message nor any output

Comment: If the output is completely blank but you are expecting some output, then that suggests some kind of serious error in PHP. Have you turned on error reporting as mentioned above?

Comment: yes the error reporting is on and i was expecting that it will fetch out all the records from that table

Answer (score 1):

```
$test_q = $config->query("SELECT * FROM `attempts`");
print_r($test_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Because attempts is a mysql function like left, right, min, max etc.

Comment: that should not matter as long it is set between any kind of valid quotes

Comment: oh ok didn't see you inserted it, sorry :]

Comment: My MySQL can use the name "attempts" just fine on a table, and I can't find any reference to a MySQL function called "attempts". Where did you find any info on that a function like that actually even exists?

Comment: Ya i did that also but it still didn't worked so i changed the table name but i wonder when i tried on other scripts it worked and there is no error in this script believe me its a long piece of code so i can't post it